# Oracle table grant

Tags: sql, oracle

I granted some operation for a user. But after that, how can i see which operations was granted by me for that user? Shortly to say
1. How do we see which operation for a table is granted to a user? 
2. Is this possible to lose grant suddenly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1.You may use below query to view privilege:

```
select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where owner='owner_name' and table_name='table name';
```

but you need DBA privileged for this. you may also use USER_TAB_PRIVS too.

2. No its not possible. Until your DBA does this intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

From user point of view it is possible to lose grant suddenly but it means there was an action which you haven't been aware of like:

swapping table during some import 
 
swapping synonyms over table (if you access thru synonym) 
 
some changes in roles/privs by DBA

Or you can just have access via role so you can select directly but not through procedure